# Can't move variable outside of function to be used

Tags: javascript

I am really struggling with this. I have created a form which calculates what the person owes based on how many people in a tent and if they are paying by credit card. The amounts update depending on the selection. When the user submits they should be redirected to PayPal with the total amount on the end of the url, I.e:

**PayPal.me/240 for £240 or PayPal.me/600 for £600**

The issue is my price variable is outside of my other function which sets the redirect, and the price amount never makes it to the redirect.

This is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
    <select name='field_0' id='field_0' class='text_select' onchange="pricecalc()"   >  
<option value="2 people" >2 people</option> 
<option value="3 people" >3 people</option> 
<option value="4 people" >4 people</option> 
<option value="5 people" >5 people</option> 
<option value="6 people" >6 people</option> 
</select>

    <select name='field_1' id='field_1' class='text_select' onchange="pricecalc()"   >  
<option value="Bank transfer" >Bank transfer</option>   
<option value="Debit card" >Debit card</option> 
<option value="Credit card + 3.4%" >Credit card + 3.4%</option> 
</select>         
<b>Total Price</b>
<span id="cost">Hello World!</span>
<b>Price Each</b>
<span id="costeach">Hello World!</span>
```

Relevant JS:

```
var myprice;
function pricecalc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("field_0");
  var quantity = a.value.substring(0, 1);
  var b = document.getElementById("field_1");
  var type = b.value;

  if (quantity == '2') {
    var rate = '120';
  } else if (quantity == '3') {
    var rate = '110';
  } else {
    var rate = '100';
  }

  myprice = rate * quantity;
  if (type == 'Credit card + 3.4%') {
    myprice = myprice * 1.034;
  }

  var price_each = (myprice / quantity);
  document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = myprice;
  document.getElementById("costeach").innerHTML = price_each;
}

function PHPFMG( formID ){
    var redirect = 'https://www.paypal.me/tim/' + myprice;
```

Comment: How/when is `PHPFMG()` called?

Comment: What is the value you get for var redirect in PHPFMG? Is it 'https://www.paypal.me/tim/undefined'?

Comment: @dsch yes it is undefined but it should be 240/500 etc

Comment: As Xatenev aksed, it best if we can see how and when PHPFMG is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would recommend doing this instead**

```
function pricecalc() {
  var myprice;
  var a = document.getElementById("field_0");
  var quantity = a.value.substring(0, 1);
  var b = document.getElementById("field_1");
  var type = b.value;

  if (quantity == '2') {
    var rate = '120';
  } else if (quantity == '3') {
    var rate = '110';
  } else {
    var rate = '100';
  }

  myprice = rate * quantity;
  if (type == 'Credit card + 3.4%') {
    myprice = myprice * 1.034;
  }

  var price_each = (myprice / quantity);
  document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = myprice;
  document.getElementById("costeach").innerHTML = price_each;

  return myprice;
}
```

**Then**

```
function PHPFMG( formID ){
    var myprice = pricecalc();
    var redirect = 'https://www.paypal.me/tim/' + myprice;
}
```

**This way you don't polute the global scope**